# ASP NET MVC не грузятся данные из файла

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Есть ASP.NET MVC сайт, есть на входе файл Excel, содержимое файла нужно загрузить через сайт в БД. Возникает проблема скорей всего с таймаутом соединения, появляется "ERR_CONNECTION_RESET" - Не удается получить доступ к сайту. Файл весит 8МБ, количество записей 350 000. (может быть больше около 800 тыс).
В Web.config у меня на данный момент указано

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="16384" executionTimeout="3600"/>
```

Метод отвечающий за загрузку, пока написал таким образом:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UploadLsGis(HttpPostedFileBase upload2)
    {            
        List<LsKvitGis> l = new List<LsKvitGis>();
        if (upload2 != null && upload2.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            int SN = 1;
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(upload2.FileName);
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Files"), fileName);
            upload2.SaveAs(path);
            using (XLWorkbook workBook = new XLWorkbook(path))
            {
                var ws = workBook.Worksheet(1);
                int lastrow = ws.LastCellUsed().Address.RowNumber;
                while (SN<=lastrow)
                {                        
                    l.Add(new LsKvitGis {
                        LS = ws.Row(SN).Cell(1).Value.ToString(),
                        LSGis = ws.Row(SN).Cell(2).Value.ToString()
                    });
                    SN++;
                }
            }
            db.lsKvitGiss.RemoveRange(from s in db.lsKvitGiss select s); //удаляю что было раньше
            db.lsKvitGiss.AddRange(l); // добавляю
            db.SaveChanges(); // сохраняю
            ViewBag.Message = "Файл с ЛС ГИС загружен";
        }
        return View("Index");
    }
```

Готов к критике!:)

На локалхосте загружается файл целиком без проблем. На продакшене грузятся небольшие файлы (3800 строк загрузил), большие - не грузятся.

**UPD1**
Выяснил, что хостер ограничивает ресурсы, из-за этого загрузка не выполняется.
Теперь нужно понять, как обойти ограничения хостера? бить файлы на стороне пользователя не вариант, если на сервере, то как это можно сделать?

Comment: Да, файлы поменьше грузятся (3800 строк загрузил)

Comment: где у вас опубликован сервис? Хостер у вас какой?

Comment: Сайт хостится на reg.ru

Comment: что значит бить файл на стороне сервера? Вы как раз должны бить на стороне клиента, и собирать его на стороне сервера.

Comment: Возможно некорректно выразился...пользователь нажимает на кнопку "загрузить файл", выбирает один файл для загрузки, а уже сам сайт разбивать и грузить данные в БД.(во всяком случае думал в эту сторону)

Comment: Сайт(клиент) должен разбивать ваши данные на чанки(например, с помощью javascript), посылать n-ое количество POST запросов серверу, а на стороне сервера вы собираете все чанки воедино, и грузите уже туда куда вам нужно.

Comment: Никогда с таким не сталкивался...может есть у вас пример, мануал? как такое делается

Comment: а какая версия у вас MVC?

Comment: используется 5 версия

Comment: посмотрите вот эту [ссылку](https://forums.asp.net/t/1742612.aspx?How+to+upload+a+big+file+in+Mvc+). Я думаю она может вам помочь